# CLion - Erro ao executar ou debugar o código

Tags: c

**EXPLICAÇÃO**

Estou estudando sobre alocação dinâmica de memória e fiz um simples programa para resolver a seguinte situação:

*O cliente deseja fazer cadastros de um determinado número de empregados e, deseja fazer a consulta logo em seguida. O programa faz o cadastro dos empregados utilizando de um Código (individual) e Nome fornecidos pelo usuário (cliente).*

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cadastro.h"

#ifdef _WIN32   /*define o comando de limpar a tela com base no SO.*/
#define CLEAR "cls"
#else
#define CLEAR "clear"
#endif

int main() {
    int qtd_prof, tam_nome, cod;
    int stop=0;
    char continue_signal;

    Profissao *profissao;

    system(CLEAR);

    printf("Qual o número de profissoes a serem cadastradas?\n");
    printf("Insira o valor:\n");
    scanf("%d", &qtd_prof);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    profissao = (Profissao *) malloc(qtd_prof * sizeof(Profissao));

    for(int i=0; i<qtd_prof; i++) {
        system(CLEAR);

        printf("Qual o tamanho do %dº nome?\n", i+1);
        printf("Insira o valor:\n");
        scanf("%d", &tam_nome);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        profissao[i].codigo = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
        profissao[i].nome = (char *) malloc(tam_nome*sizeof(char));

        printf("======================================\n");
        printf("Qual o codigo do %dº cadastro:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &(*profissao[i].codigo));
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        printf("======================================\n");
        printf("Qual o nome do %dº cadastro: (MAX: %d)\n", i+1, tam_nome);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", profissao[i].nome);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        /* if(feof(aux)) {          //A ideia dessa parte era averiguar a qtd de bytes inseridos.
            flag=1;
            printf("ERRO! Falha ao tentar gravar o nome.\n");
            getchar();
            break;
        } */
    }
    printf("======================================\n");
    printf("Nomes gravados com sucesso!\n");
    printf("Pressione ENTER para continuar!\n");
    getchar();

    while (!stop) {
        system(CLEAR);

        printf("Insira o codigo para consulta:\n");
        scanf("%d", &cod);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);

        for (int i = 0; i < qtd_prof; ++i) {
            if(cod == *profissao[i].codigo) {
                printf("-----------------------------\n");
                printf("Nome: %s\n", profissao[i].nome);
            }
        }

        do {
            printf("======================================\n");
            printf("Deseja fazer uma nova consulta? (S/N)\n");
            scanf("%c", &continue_signal);
            setbuf(stdin, NULL);

            if (continue_signal == 'S') {
                stop = 0;
            } else if (continue_signal == 'N') {
                stop = 1;
                printf("O programa será finalizado!\n");
            }
        }while (continue_signal != 'S' && continue_signal != 'N');
    }

    for(int i=0; i<qtd_prof; i++) {
        free(profissao[i].codigo);
        free(profissao[i].nome);

        free(profissao);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**cadastro.h**

```
#ifndef CADASTRO_H
#define CADASTRO_H

typedef struct{
    int *codigo;
    char *nome;
} Profissao;

#endif //CADASTRO_H
```

> Inicialmente, só tem a **struct** **Profissao**, a qual possui a estruturação do cadastro de cada empregado que será implementado pela função **main.c**.

**PROBLEMA**

A questão é que o código compila e executa perfeitamente utilizando o **gcc** (linux). Mas quando eu tento compilar de dentro do CLion (IDE da JetBrains) eu me deparo com o seguinte problema:

[image: ErrorCode]

> O código não chega nem mesmo a mostrar o primeiro **printf** no terminal.

[image: CLion Settings]

> O CLion detectou o GDB, CMake e Valgrind corretamente e as dependências estão todas instaladas.

Estou postando aqui, no *StackOverflow*, em busca de alguém que tenha passado pela mesma situação e possa me ajudar.

Comment: Colocou algum *breakpoint* antes de lançar o programa em modo *debug* ?

Comment: Para testar sim, mas primeiro eu tentei sem nenhum _breakpoint_ e deu erro mesmo assim. Quando eu coloquei o _breakpoint_, eu coloquei no primeiro **malloc** da função porque achei que o erro podia ser na alocação dinânima. Mas mesmo assim, não aparece os **printfs** no terminal e ele diz: "Process finished with exit code 1".